# Apache log file parsing via Python

Tags: python

I am making a python log parser script where I need to count the number of logs whose status code is 200 from a log file.

Here are some of the logs from the file:

```
120.115.144.240 - - [29/Aug/2017:04:40:03 -0400] "GET /apng/assembler-2.0/assembler2.php HTTP/1.1" 404 231 "http://littlesvr.ca/apng/history.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.101 Safari/537.36"

202.167.250.99 - - [29/Aug/2017:04:41:10 -0400] "GET /apng/images/o_sample.png?1424751982?1424776117 HTTP/1.1" 200 115656 "http://bbs.mydigit.cn/read.php?tid=2186780&fpage=3" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36"

14.152.69.236 - - [29/Aug/2017:04:41:41 -0400] "GET /apng/images/o_sample.png?1424751982?1424776117 HTTP/1.1" 304 - "http://bbs.mydigit.cn/read.php?tid=2205351" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 7.1.2; zh-CN; NX510J Build/NJH47D) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/40.0.2214.89 UCBrowser/11.6.6.951 Mobile Safari/537.36"

60.4.236.27 - - [29/Aug/2017:04:42:46 -0400] "GET /apng/images/o_sample.png?1424751982?1424776117 HTTP/1.1" 200 115656 "http://bbs.mydigit.cn/read.php?tid=1952896" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/45.0.2454.101 Safari/537.36"

58.62.17.190 - - [29/Aug/2017:04:50:01 -0400] "GET /apng/gif_apng_webp1.html HTTP/1.1" 200 935 "http://dev.qq.com/topic/582939577ef9c5b708556b0d" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36"
```

I have tried this code but the only output I'm getting is a long list of closed brackets `[]`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys
import re

f = open('accesslogfile', 'r')
print('Reading log files... done.')
nooflines = f.readlines()

for line in nooflines:    
    regex = re.match(r'\d{200}\s', line)
    print(regex)
f.close()
```

In this case, I know the output should be `3` (As there are only three logs that have the status code 200) but I can't seem to get it. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks :)

Comment: `r'\d{200}\s'` matches a 200 digit number. I don't think that's what you want. ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas


df = pandas.read_csv("log_path", sep='\s+', names=[i for i in range(10)])

print(df.loc[df[6] == 200])
print(len(df.loc[df[6] == 200]))
```

Answer (score 1):

It's so simple：

```
re.findall('(HTTP/1.1\" 200)',line)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change your regex to `(200)\s`. What you are doing is matching 200 of any digit and then one character of white space (like a line break of a space or a tab). What you want is to match the token "200 ". So just put `(200)\s` as your regex.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing following things wrong here.

> 1. Using match instead of search. See difference [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3346076/python-re-match-vs-re-search)
> 2. Using {200} instead of {3}
> 3. And not adding \s in the regex

So your regex should be

```
re.search(r'\s\d{3}\s', line)
```

So you have the following code:

```
import re
counter = 0
for line in log.split('\n'):
    if line:
        regex = re.search(r'\s\d{3}\s', line)
        if regex.group().strip() == '200':
            counter += 1
print('Found ', counter)
```

Output:

**('Found ', 3)**